# How can we instantiate spring beans in Web applications

Tags: spring

In most of the spring tutorials that I see the spring bean instantiation is like below in the class with the `main` method. But in real world scenario this is not how it works right? Say in case of a web application, how can we do the below and were do we need to do it?

```
ApplcationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicaitonContext.xml");
context.getBean("blah");
```

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web applications with spring usually have defined a little something called listener in `web.xml` like this:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This listener is responsible for initialization `XmlWebApplicationContext` (it's implementation of `ApplicationContext` just like `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`) with  `/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml` as a default configuration file location if not redefined.

So

> ApplicationContext context = new
>   ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicaitonContext.xml");

is done automatically.

As for the

> context.getBean("blah");

well it is possible, you just need to inject `ApplicationContext` into any bean like:

```
@Component
class AnyBean {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    void doSomethingWithBlah() {
        context.getBean("blah").doSomething();
    }
}
```

But that is not what spring was meant for. You supposed to inject "blah" bean with `@Autowired` or `@Inject` instead of interacting with application context directly.

Please refer to spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) for details.